# Spring Data Couchbase - Getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1 for a paging query

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I am working on a requirement for implementing pagination using Spring Data Couchbase[Spring Boot version 2.4.2].

Custom Repository interface extends PagingAndSortingRepository

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DocumentEntity, String> { 

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} " + 
            "AND attribute1 IS NOT NULL " +
           "AND ANY id IN attribute2 SATISFIES id IN [ #{#values} ] END"
    )
    Page<DocumentEntity> findByValue(@Param("values") String valueToBeSearched, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Index has been created for attribute1 & attribute2.

attribute2 data type is `Set<String>` .

Following exception is thrown:

```
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$collectVariables$0(ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:116)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1032)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.collectVariables(ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.StringBasedN1qlQueryParser.getExpression(StringBasedN1qlQueryParser.java:413)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.StringBasedN1qlQueryParser.<init>(StringBasedN1qlQueryParser.java:126)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.StringN1qlQueryCreator.<init>(StringN1qlQueryCreator.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.N1qlRepositoryQueryExecutor.execute(N1qlRepositoryQueryExecutor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.CouchbaseRepositoryQuery.execute(CouchbaseRepositoryQuery.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
```

The above query works if I invoke the above method without pagination(adding Offset and Limit fields to the above query) i.e.
List findByValue(@Param("values") String valueToBeSearched);

Is there anything missing in the configuration?

I have tried extending CouchbaseRepository<> (which extends PagingAndSortingRepository) but same error response.

Comment: I am facing same problem, have you resolved it ?